# Can 99% isopropyl alcohol be stored in a clear container?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, alcohols, containers

I'm planning to get hold of some [99% isopropyl alcohol](https://www.amazon.co.uk/500mL-Pharmaceutical-Isopropyl-Alcohol-Isopropanol/dp/B00WLAS9W8/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1522105017) (aka rubbing alcohol) for the purpose of cleaning electronics, and am going to transfer it from the plastic bottle it comes in to a smaller, clear [dropper bottle](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bee-Beautiful-Bottle-Pipette-Bottles/dp/B00CVBBU1E/ref=sr_1_10?s=officeproduct&ie=UTF8&qid=1522111001) or [similar](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Toruiwa-Applicator-Dropper-Plastic-Squeezable/dp/B074T9FJLJ/ref=sr_1_4?s=officeproduct&ie=UTF8&qid=1522111001). However, I vaguely remember being told that isopropyl alcohol shouldn't be stored in a clear container - possibly something to do with speedier evaporation, but I'm really not sure.

Is this true? Are there any downsides to storing 99% isopropanol in a clear container? Will storing the solution in direct sunlight change this at all?

Comment: Generally more transfer means purity goes down. However this can be negligible.  No a clean container does nothing bad. Shadow and caps are generally better. Storing a solvent with no cap is not safe or likely no storing at all :)

Comment: Ps isopropyl alcohol for cleaning is justified in industrial environments. For most cases ethanol etc work as well

Comment: @Alchimista What do you mean by shadow?

Comment: I mean common sense.  Do not store anything on a beach

Comment: @Alchimista Definitely don't. Pirates are everywhere!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not expect that isopropanol would evaporate appreciably from a properly sealed container. Rather the main purpose of storing isopropanol out of light is to prevent peroxide formation.  Isopropanol can form peroxides and when [distilled they can concentrate and explode](https://cen.acs.org/articles/94/i31/Chemical-safety-peroxide-formation-isopropanol.html). A clear container allows more light to pass and thus more peroxides to form.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert, but I have some experience dealing with solvents such as isoproponal in a research setting. Normally in a lab solvents are not stored in the open, exposed to light, for the exact reason that you mentioned- speedier evaporation. Hence, even if you were to store it in a clear container, I would make sure to cap it and stow it away in a dark place as soon as you are finished with it.

Comment: Alcohols exposed to light form *peroxides*. The guy responsible for lab safety in your place should get a hard kick in the back if he didn't explain *why* exactly you have to keep most solvents not only cool but also in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you’re talking about with the clear container problem is hydrogen peroxide, which is stored in brown containers because light causes oxidation to occur which causes decomposition of the hydrogen peroxide into water. Rubbing alcohol does not have this problem with the light.